# Layout glitches with Xcode 14 & iOS 16

Tags: ios, xcode, ios16, xcode14

I've upgraded to Xcode 14 and iOS 16, and now the app has a layout glitch when moving to new screens. You can see in the gif below the text and buttons move in the first few milliseconds when moving to a new screen. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: no idea, IOS 16 and Xcode 14 causing so many issues to me as well.

Comment: Can you share the code? your view is SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar Storyboard. BTW, I switched back to XCode 13, and it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

`Xcode 14.1 Beta 3` should fix this but I recommend keep using Xcode 13 for now until a stable release come out.

Comment: Unfortunately still broken in Xcode 14.3.